# Prevent memory allocation from ballooning when reading files from disk

Tags: php, memory-management

I have a script that reads many small files (<2MB) from disk and writes them to a zip file using a library called [ZipStream](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP/blob/master/src/ZipStream.php#L301) (the line in the code shows where this happens).

When running this with lots of files, I noticed that each time I call `addFileFromPath` (follow link above to see exact line in code), the allocated memory to PHP increases (`memory_get_usage(true)`) and **stays increased**, even though the actual memory usage the process is using (`memory_get_usage(false)`) remains low after the variables holding the file read from disk are deleted (as I expected).

PHP will eventually hit the memory allocation limit defined in php.ini.

So this is really a question about how PHP allocates memory vs how it's used. It seems the script keeps allocating memory each time I read the file into memory, instead of reusing already allocated memory. Is that correct?

Is there a way I can read these small files into memory without the allocated memory ballooning forever?

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us how you are reading these small files we'd be able to answer you